# Magento 2 Customer address attribute not saved while creating new order from admin

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, custom-attributes, customer-address, admin-order-create

I have created one **"Customer address"** type of attribute name **"Suburb"**, It successfully created.

It shows on Checkout, Customer create(admin) and Create New Order address(Admin) section, While It works fine with checkout as well as create customer but not working with Create new order.

Here install script:

```
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'suburb', [
                'label' => 'Suburb',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'position' => 70,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]);


            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'suburb')
                ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer_address',
                    'customer_address_edit',
                    'customer_register_address'
                ]]);
            $attribute->save();
```

I tried to create new Order and fill all required data including `Suburb`.
[image]

But when I tried to Submit Order It shows me error '**Suburb**`  is a required value. It's shown that filled value of suburb is not being saved too.

[image]
Please help, Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied your custom attribute to the appropriate node inside the fieldset.xml configuration? See the following file:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/fieldset.xml
```

Looking at your screenshots it seems you have added your attribute to the address object. See the 'sales_copy_order_billing_address' and 'sales_copy_order_shipping_address' fieldset nodes.

**Update**

I recently had to save a custom order attribute to the database when creating the order via the admin area. I found that adding the attribute to the fieldset.xml didn't work when creating an order in the admin. To save the attribute I created a plugin and an observer. See details below:

*Plugin*

Class: Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create

Method: importPostData()

This saved the custom attribute to the quote object used to create the order in the quote management class.

---

*Observer*

Event: sales_model_service_quote_submit_before

This is used to add the custom attribute to the older model just before the model is saved to the DB.

Hope the above is useful for you.